# map points between two triangles in 3D space

Tags: math, geometry, computational-geometry

**EDIT**

**I don't know is it important, but destination triangle angles may be different than these of source. Does that fact makes transformation non-affine ? (i'm not sure)**

[image]

I have two triangles in 3D space. Given that i know (x,y,z) of point in first triangle and i know vectors V1,V2,V3. I need to find point (x',y',z'). What transformation i should do to point (x,y,z) with vectors V1,V2,V3 to get that transformed point in the second triangle ?

Thanks for help !!!

Comment: Affine transformations allow translations and therefore the issue you raise with angles isn't really a player by itself.  Linear transformations can be used to change the shape, size and orientation of the triangle without any real issues.  Affine transformations are needed when the resulting linear transformation places the object in the incorrect position in your vector space and you need to reposition it.  I've updated my answer to allow a solution to be found without application of any advanced techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a matrix transformation T such that T X = X', where X is the matrix whose columns are the co-ordinates of the vertexes of the first triangle and X' is the same for the second triangle. Multiplying each side by the inverse of X yields T = X' X<sup>-1</sup>.

Comment: That's what I was thinking at first, but as I looked at it, it became clear that the problem as presented is underconstrained. I believe a unique solution is possible once the distance constraints are included, but finding that unique solution requires convex programming and can't be solved using the linear method you outlined.

Comment: @andand The matrix transformation takes all three vertexes to their counterparts. It is also a linear transformation; therefore, any point in the interior of the first triangle will be transformed into the interior of the second in a way that maintains proportional distance from the vertexes.

Comment: Suppose the origin is one of the points interior to the first triangle, but it is not a point interior to the second.  This can't happen using linear transformations; the origin is always mapped to the origin.  The problem as stated requires an affine  (vice linear) transformation, so that the origin in the domain can be mapped to something other than the origin in the range.

Comment: @andand You're right. The X and X' in my answer should be constituted from the vectors from each triangle's center of mass (COM) to it's vertexes. Transforming a point in triangle 1 then comprises 1) subtracting the COM of the first triangle; 2) applying T; and 3) adding the displacement vector from triangle 1 COM to triangle 2 COM.

Answer (score 5):

The short answer is that this is more complicated than it at first appears, and the nature of the constraints you are placing on the problem require some more advanced techniques than you might think.

So, by way of an explanation, I'm going to change your notation a bit.  Consider 3 pairs of vectors (these correspond to your the vertices of the two triangles in your problem):

```
u = <u0, u1, u2, 1>
u' = <u0', u1', u2', 1>

v = <v0, v1, v2, 1>
v' = <v0', v1', v2', 1>

w = <w0, w1, w2, 1>
w' = <w0', w1', w2', 1>
```

Ordinarily, your problem would be solved through the identification of the linear transformation of the form:

```
    |a0,0  a0,1  a0,2  a0,3|
A = |a1,0  a1,1  a1,2  a1,3|
    |a2,0  a2,1  a2,2  a2,3|
    |0     0     0     1   |
```

such that:

```
Au = u'
Av = v'
Aw = w'
```

This formulation is needed because the transformation seems to be a 3-D affine transformation, not a 3-D linear transformation.  If it were a linear transformation, any triangle containing the origin would necessarily map to another triangle containing the origin.  Extending to a 4-D space allows 4-D linear transformation to be used to perform 3-D affine transformation.

That said, the first thing to notice is that this problem is underconstrained (9 equations with 12 unknowns); there is no unique solution.  There are in fact infinitely many.  However, your problem is somewhat more constrained than this, so there's some hope.  You have the additional constraints given a vector

```
p = <p0, p1, p2, 1>
```

find

```
Ap = p' = <p0', p1', p2', 1>
```

such that (using your definition vectors ***a***, ***b***, and ***c***)

```
|u - p|   |u' - p'|
------- = ---------
|u - a|   |u' - Aa|

|v - p|   |v' - p'|
------- = ---------
|v - b|   |v' - Ab|

|w - p|   |w' - p'|
------- = ---------
|w - c|   |w' - Ac|
```

While this presents an additional constraint on your problem, it changes it from being one that could easily solved using linear methods to one that requires [Convex Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_programming) to find a unique solution.

That said, here are some possible aproaches:

- Go ahead and use convex programming to solve the problem.  While more difficult to solve than linear problems, they are not really all that hard to solve.
- Revert to the 2D case, rather than the 3D case.  This can be done without resorting to the non-linear constraints those distance measurements impose.
- Select a fourth point and instead of working on triangles, work on tetrahedra instead.  This again removes the non-linearity from the problem.

**UPDATE:**  I've given this some thought and I see a way to generate the correct affine transformation without using convex programming.  It can be done by generating a fourth vertex for each of the triangles, called `y` and `y'`:

```
y = u + (v-u)×(w-u)
y' = u' + (v'-u')×(w'-u')
```

where `×` is the 3-D cross product of the two vectors (i.e. omit the final 1 in each vector; but remember to append the 1 onto y and y' once you have them calculated).  From there, you can apply the standard technique of creating matrices M and M' from column vectors:

```
 M = <u, v, w, y>
 M' = <u', v', w', y'>
```

and use the method Steve Emmerson suggested (in 4-D rather than 3-D):

```
AM = M'
AMM-1 = M'M-1
A = M'M-1
```

Comment: Thanks for deep analysis of the problem.

Comment: Great answer. I was stuck at the point where I had 9 equations with 12 unknowns when I found your post. I have question here: why **y** an **y'** works as the fourth point? I mean, it is not an independent, equally good you could use center points of the triangles **y = mean(x,y,z)** (OK, OK, probably you couldn't, but I don't see why the cross-product is better)

Comment: You can use any vector which is linearly independent of the legs of the triangle.  y and y' being the the cross products of the other legs satisfy that constraint and in essence creates a simplex.  Using the mean creates a linearly dependent vector, and so M will not have an inverse.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might be looking for barycentric coordinates?

Comment: +1 yes. Find the barycentric coordinates of a point on the source triangle and then locate those barycentric coordinates on the destination triangle.

Answer (score 3):

check andand's comments for theory

// Qt code

```
QMatrix4x4 m;
QMatrix4x4 t1;
QMatrix4x4 t2;

QVector3D v1(0,0,0);
QVector3D v2(0,1,0);
QVector3D v3(1,0,0);
QVector3D v4 = v1 + QVector3D::crossProduct(v2-v1, v3-v1);

QVector3D v1p(0,0,2);
QVector3D v2p(0,3,2);
QVector3D v3p(1,0,1);
QVector3D v4p = v1p + QVector3D::crossProduct(v2p-v1p, v3p-v1p);

t1.setColumn(0, QVector4D(v1, 1));
t1.setColumn(1, QVector4D(v2, 1));
t1.setColumn(2, QVector4D(v3, 1));
t1.setColumn(3, QVector4D(v4, 1));

t2.setColumn(0, QVector4D(v1p, 1));
t2.setColumn(1, QVector4D(v2p, 1));
t2.setColumn(2, QVector4D(v3p, 1));
t2.setColumn(3, QVector4D(v4p, 1));

m = t2 * t1.inverted();

for(float i=0.0; i<2.5; i+=0.05)
{
    QVector4D p(0.2+i,i,0,1);
    QVector4D pp( m * p );

    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
    glColor4f(1,1,1,1);
    glVertex3d(p.x(), p.y(), p.z());

    glColor4f(1,0,1,1);
    glVertex3d(pp.x(), pp.y(), pp.z());
    glEnd();
}
```

And a video of this code in action:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yOU90pBoyZY

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the vectors to each point. Point + Vector == new Point. This is basically the opposite of creating the Vector in the first place: V1 == (x1'-x1, y1'-y1, z1'-z1), so (x1', y1', z1') == (x1+V1x, y1+v1y, z1+V1z).

Comment: I don't think this answers the question. I think the OP means that (x, y, z) is an arbitrary point in the triangle.

Comment: Yep i feel too that this is not solution, because point should be affected by ALL three vectors V1,V2,V3 (because all vertices changes), not by just one V1.

Answer (score 0):

Let

```
 x = αx1 + βx2 + γx3
```

Then
     x' = αx1' + βx2' + γx3'
So

```
x' = α(x1+V1) + β(x2+V2) + γ(x3+V3)
```

Comment: This is a 3-D linear transformation.  The problem requires a 3-D affine transformation.

Comment: I don't exactly understood. Did you mean: x' = α(x1+V1.x) + β(x2+V2.x) + γ(x3+V3.x) ?? Also How to calculate α,β,γ ?